# Centering a word around a specific character using vanilla HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a simple "Speed reading" html page as practice where I need to follow some RSVP rules, my problem is centering the word around a specific character based on this criteria:

```
word length = 0-1 -> first letter 
word length = 2-5 -> second letter 
word length = 6-9 -> third letter 
word length = 10-13 ->fourth letter 
word length >13 -> fifth letter
```

I got everything working except for the centering part, I tried a lot of solutions but I failed to get any of them to work.

Here is a demo(not mine) of how this centering the word works:
https://github.com/royha/jsreader

Here is my work:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/speedreader.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>SpeedReader</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="previewArea">
            <div id="outputText">
                <span id='left'></span><!-- 
                --><span id='mid'></span><!-- 
                --><span id='right'></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="controls">
            <div class="sub-controls">
                <label class="labels" for="startBtn">Play Controls</label>
                <input type="button" class="btn" id="startBtn" value="Start">
                <input type="button" class="btn" id="stopBtn" value="Stop">
            </div>

            <div class="sub-controls">
                <label class="labels" for="speedOptions">Speed</label>
                <select id="speedOptions">
                    <option value="500">50 wpm</option>
                    <option value="200">300 wpm</option>
                    <option value="171" selected='selected'>350 wpm</option>
                    <option value="150">400 wpm</option>
                    <option value="133">450 wpm</option>
                    <option value="120">500 wpm</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="sub-controls">
                <label class="labels">Size</label>
                <input type="radio" id="medSize" value="36">
                <label for="medSize">Medium</label>
                <input type="radio" id="bigSize" value="48">
                <label for="bigSize">Big</label>
                <input type="radio" id="biggerSize" value="60">
                <label for="biggerSize">Bigger</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="inputArea">
            <label class="labels">Input Text</label>
            <textarea id="input" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="js/speedreader.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    background-color: #EAF6F6;
    font-family: Garamomd, Verdana ,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 70%;
}
.header{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#previewArea{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #8EBEBE;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
#outputText{
    width: 400px;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 36;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    /* left: 0px; */
}

.controls{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sub-controls{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.labels{
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8EBEBE;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#input{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn{
    width: 70px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.btn:disabled{
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: wheat;
}

.btn:active{
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.inputArea{
    width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
}

#mid{
    color: red;
    /* position: relative; */

}
```

Javascript:

```
// Input
const input = document.querySelector('#input');

// Buttons
const startBtn = document.querySelector('#startBtn');
const stopBtn = document.querySelector('#stopBtn');
stopBtn.disabled = true;

// Dropdown
const speedOptions = document.querySelector('#speedOptions');

// Size options
const medSize = document.querySelector('#medSize');
medSize.checked = true;
const bigSize = document.querySelector('#bigSize');
const biggerSize = document.querySelector('#biggerSize');

// Output
const outputText = document.querySelector('#outputText');
const left = document.querySelector('#left');
const mid = document.querySelector('#mid');
const right = document.querySelector('#right');


var arr = [];
var isPlaying = false;
var i = 0;
var timer;
var currFont = 36;

function playAnim(){
    if(i >= arr.length){
        clearInterval(timer);
        i = 0;
        isPlaying = false;
        startBtn.disabled = false;
        stopBtn.disabled = true;
        return;
    }

    if(arr[i].length <= 1){
        mid.innerHTML = arr[i];
    } else if(arr[i].length <= 5){
        //left.innerHTML = arr[i][0];
        //mid.innerHTML = arr[i][1];
        //right.innerHTML = arr[i].slice(2);

        var pad = "";
        for(let k = 0; k < 8-1; k++){
            pad = "&nbsp;" + pad;
        }
        //left.innerHTML = pad + arr[i][0];
        outputText.innerHTML = `${pad}${arr[i][0]}<span id='mid'>${arr[i][1]}</span>${arr[i].slice(2)}`;
    }
    //Rest of the conditions in criteria
    i++;
}

speedOptions.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if(!isPlaying){
        return;
    }
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(playAnim, parseInt(speedOptions.value));
});

startBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    stopBtn.disabled = false;
    startBtn.disabled = true;
    outputText.style.fontSize = currFont
    isPlaying = true;

    arr = [];
    var tempArr = input.value.split(/[\s\t\n]+/);
    tempArr.forEach(word => {
        var check = word.split(/[,!\?.;]+/);
        if(check.length > 1){
            arr.push(check[0]);
        }
        arr.push(check[0]);
    });

    console.log(arr);

    timer = setInterval(playAnim, parseInt(speedOptions.value));
});

stopBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    clearInterval(timer);
    i = 0;
    outputText.innerHTML = '';
    startBtn.disabled = false;
    stopBtn.disabled = true;
});

medSize.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    bigSize.checked = false;
    biggerSize.checked = false;
    currFont = 36;
    if(isPlaying) outputText.style.fontSize = currFont;
});

bigSize.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    medSize.checked = false;
    biggerSize.checked = false;
    currFont = 48;
    if(isPlaying) outputText.style.fontSize = currFont;
});

biggerSize.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    bigSize.checked = false;
    medSize.checked = false;
    currFont = 60;
    if(isPlaying) outputText.style.fontSize = currFont;
});
```

Layout:
[image: LAYOUT]

What I want to illustrate:

[image]

I am a beginner to web programming in general so excuse my potentially bad code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you create a [mre] that shows just your attempt at centering a word?

Comment: @ChrisG I haven't been successful in doing it myself in order to create it, but this github repo has exactly what I mean if you run the html or even watch the video in the readme -> https://github.com/royha/jsreader - I just can't see the logic behind his approach to be able to apply it to my app. You'll notice the word is centered around a highlighted character.

Comment: "centering the word around a specific character" what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Harshit I explained in the above comment, I am sorry if it isn't very clear in the question.

Comment: You can use absolutely positioned elements for this: https://jsfiddle.net/qozkjns0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a monospace font is being used it is possible to center on a given character by the method given, padding with non-breaking spaces.

There are just a couple of things that need to change to ensure the second character always remains at the center (for the example given, >1 but <=5 characters). The width of the output text is set to auto so it can take up its natural width when the characters are added and the setting of padding spaces needs to alter so it puts just enough spaces into the first part of the string to make sure the number of characters there is equal to the number of characters after the second (centered) character so that loop becomes:

```
   for ( let k=0; k<(arr[i].length - 3 ); k++) {
        pad = "&nbsp;" + pad;
    }
```

Obviously the loop count will be different for the cases where there are more characters.

Here''s the snippet:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/speedreader.css">
    <style>
    .container{
    background-color: #EAF6F6;
    font-family: Garamomd, Verdana ,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 70%;
}
.header{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#previewArea{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #8EBEBE;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
#outputText{
    width: auto;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 36;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    /* left: 0px; */
}

.controls{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sub-controls{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.labels{
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8EBEBE;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#input{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn{
    width: 70px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.btn:disabled{
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: wheat;
}

.btn:active{
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.inputArea{
    width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#mid {
    color: red;
}


  
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>SpeedReader</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="previewArea">
            <div id="outputText">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="controls">
            <div class="sub-controls">
                <label class="labels" for="startBtn">Play Controls</label>
                <input type="button" class="btn" id="startBtn" value="Start">
                <input type="button" class="btn" id="stopBtn" value="Stop">
            </div>

            <div class="sub-controls">
                <label class="labels" for="speedOptions">Speed</label>
                <select id="speedOptions">
                    <option value="500">50 wpm</option>
                    <option value="200">300 wpm</option>
                    <option value="171" selected='selected'>350 wpm</option>
                    <option value="150">400 wpm</option>
                    <option value="133">450 wpm</option>
                    <option value="120">500 wpm</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="sub-controls">
                <label class="labels">Size</label>
                <input type="radio" id="medSize" value="36">
                <label for="medSize">Medium</label>
                <input type="radio" id="bigSize" value="48">
                <label for="bigSize">Big</label>
                <input type="radio" id="biggerSize" value="60">
                <label for="biggerSize">Bigger</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="inputArea">
            <label class="labels">Input Text</label>
            <textarea id="input" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
// Input
const input = document.querySelector('#input');

// Buttons
const startBtn = document.querySelector('#startBtn');
const stopBtn = document.querySelector('#stopBtn');
stopBtn.disabled = true;

// Dropdown
const speedOptions = document.querySelector('#speedOptions');

// Size options
const medSize = document.querySelector('#medSize');
medSize.checked = true;
const bigSize = document.querySelector('#bigSize');
const biggerSize = document.querySelector('#biggerSize');

// Output
const outputText = document.querySelector('#outputText');
const left = document.querySelector('#left');
const mid = document.querySelector('#mid');
const right = document.querySelector('#right');


var arr = [];
var isPlaying = false;
var i = 0;
var timer;
var currFont = 36;

function playAnim(){
    if(i >= arr.length){
        clearInterval(timer);
        i = 0;
        isPlaying = false;
        startBtn.disabled = false;
        stopBtn.disabled = true;
        return;
    }

    if(arr[i].length <= 1){
        mid.innerHTML = arr[i];
    } else if(arr[i].length <= 5){
        //left.innerHTML = arr[i][0];
        //mid.innerHTML = arr[i][1];
        //right.innerHTML = arr[i].slice(2);

        var pad = "";
       // for(let k = 0; k < 8-1; k++){
       for ( let k=0; k<(arr[i].length - 3 ); k++) {
            pad = "&nbsp;" + pad;
        }
        //left.innerHTML = pad + arr[i][0];
        outputText.innerHTML = `${pad}${arr[i][0]}<span id='mid'>${arr[i][1]}</span>${arr[i].slice(2)}`;
    }
    //Rest of the conditions in criteria
    i++;
}

speedOptions.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if(!isPlaying){
        return;
    }
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(playAnim, parseInt(speedOptions.value));
});

startBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    stopBtn.disabled = false;
    startBtn.disabled = true;
    outputText.style.fontSize = currFont
    isPlaying = true;

    arr = [];
    var tempArr = input.value.split(/[\s\t\n]+/);
    tempArr.forEach(word => {
        var check = word.split(/[,!\?.;]+/);
        if(check.length > 1){
            arr.push(check[0]);
        }
        arr.push(check[0]);
    });

    console.log(arr);

    timer = setInterval(playAnim, parseInt(speedOptions.value));
});

stopBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    clearInterval(timer);
    i = 0;
    outputText.innerHTML = '';
    startBtn.disabled = false;
    stopBtn.disabled = true;
});

medSize.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    bigSize.checked = false;
    biggerSize.checked = false;
    currFont = 36;
    if(isPlaying) outputText.style.fontSize = currFont;
});

bigSize.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    medSize.checked = false;
    biggerSize.checked = false;
    currFont = 48;
    if(isPlaying) outputText.style.fontSize = currFont;
});

biggerSize.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    bigSize.checked = false;
    medSize.checked = false;
    currFont = 60;
    if(isPlaying) outputText.style.fontSize = currFont;
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the "- 3" in the condition represent ? is it the highlighted character index ? cause in that range the highlighted index is 1 according to the criteria, so I am unaware of the meaning of the 3

Comment: If you have 5 characters then there are 3 characters after the highlighted one and one before it (think of abcde - b is the highlighted one). To make the string before have the same length as the string after you have to add 2 spaces. If the string is 4 characters, you  have to add just one space and if it's 3 characters long you don't want to add any. 1 and 2 character strings are special cases.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is a long word (i.e. too long to fit all the characters that should go on the right hand side of the central character)? Maye you need to not centralise the 'mid' highlighted character but always have it 5 character places in from the left, to give consistency between very long and very short words.

Answer (score 1):

Check this codepen link - https://codepen.io/jainharshit/pen/PoWJrVj

Remove the `&nbsp;`

```
for(let k = 0; k < 8-1; k++){
    // pad = "&nbsp;" + pad;
}
```

And **css** to -

```
#outputText {
   width: 400px;
   line-height: 100px;
   font-family: monospace;
   font-size: 36;
   font-weight: bold;
   position: relative;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: The highlighted letter is still not centered between the words and each other, by that I mean if you get a 5 letter word and a 4 letter word the highlighted char wont be the same position to the eye, this video https://youtu.be/MdPaGncIUjg demonstrates my point. The highlighted character never changes position it feels fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This uses relative positioning to shift the words left by the appropriate amount, based on using a monospace font of a known size.

```js
var words = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eget luctus nunc. Nunc dapibus, justo sit amet semper posuere, risus urna bibendum velit, quis vehicula nulla nulla vitae eros. Curabitur in pretium metus. Sed maximus pretium lacus, vel laoreet dolor maximus sed. Praesent erat metus, tristique a leo ut, convallis elementum quam. Etiam et massa ut nibh commodo aliquet sit amet sit amet justo. Proin rhoncus vestibulum feugiat. Quisque volutpat metus ac diam accumsan, vitae gravida risus molestie.".split(' ');
var timer;
var wordIndex;
function start() {
    wordIndex = 0;
    timer = setInterval(animate, 200);
}

function animate() {
    if (wordIndex >= words.length) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  } else {
    var thisPosition = getFocusLetterPosition(words[wordIndex]);
    // Offset amount = position multiplied by half the font size (negated for margin-left)
    var thisOffset = (thisPosition * 10) * -1;
    var thisWord = words[wordIndex].substr(0, thisPosition-1) 
                + "<span id=\"highlighted\">" 
                + words[wordIndex].substr(thisPosition-1, 1)
                + "</span>"
                + words[wordIndex].substr(thisPosition);
    $('#text').html("<span style=\"position:relative;margin-left:" + thisOffset + "px\">" + thisWord + "</span>");
  }
  wordIndex++;
}

function getFocusLetterPosition(word) {
    var position;
    if (word.length < 2) {
    position = 1;
  } else if (word.length < 6) {
    position = 2;
  } else if (word.length < 10) {
    position = 3
  } else if (word.length < 14) {
    position = 4;
  } else {
    position = 5;
  }
  return position;
}
```

```css
#container {
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#highlighted {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <span id="text">Test</span>
</div>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
```